# Reading all input from a socket continuously

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I'm writing a simple Java client/server application for my own use. It should allow clients to send single line text messages and read multiline responses. This kind of communication should be repeatable many times using the same connection.

This is what I have in the client for reading responses:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    // processing here
}
```

The problem with this is that readLine() blocks once the server sends the first response back and the client cannot send new messages because of that. This is understandable. A naive workaround could be making the server signal the end of its output by sending some kind of a known special string value which the client would then recognize and end the reading loop. However, is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Your logic seems ok, when getting a connection you wait for a full line to arrive, process it and then wait for the next line. That is exactly what you describe you want. If you only want to read one line, remove the while, but what do you want to do instead?

Comment: The usual solution to handling this is two asynchronous threads; where one reads, the other writes, and the main thread keeps handling the GUI. And you build things on queues, so that the GUI can add messages to a queue that the writing thread can send as soon as it is free.

Comment: @Roger Lindsjö: I want to read ALL lines then send a new message then read ALL lines again and send a new message... The problem is that readLine blocks.

Comment: Then you need a marker to signal the end of your current lines. What you ask for now is that there will be an unknown number of lines, and they will take an unknown period of time to arrive, and after yet another unknown period of time there will be another unknown number of lines and you want your program do distinguish between these two groups of lines.

Answer (score 4):

Since your client should read multiple multiline responses from same connection and process the each block of response,
this might be useful for your case :

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("~~/START/~~"))
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        else if (line.equals("~~/END/~~")) {
            doSthWithParagraph(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else
            sb.append(line);
    }
```

You can use your own special string to recognize start and end of each message block.

Answer (score 1):

I would not rely on `readLine` for your main loop because `readLine` relies on "future" data (CR, or LF, or CR+LF, and return null if end of stream has been reached). Because of this, if CR is not followed by an LF, the `BufferedReader` gets stucked. This `readLine` method is more appropriate for reading file content.

In your case, I would read one character at a time with

```
while ((myChar = input.read()) != -1) {
    // processing here, storing information in a buffer and taking appropriate actions if
    // A CR or LF is found
}
```

But even this behaviour is dubious because a Unicode char can be more than one byte, so the stream could be stuck if the first byte is sent and not the second. Are you sure your communication is Unicode? If not, an `InputStream` would be more appropriate than a `Reader`.